# Magento-1.9: How to manage products as per my wish in owl corousel slider for my home page slider?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-list, category-products, owl-carousel

I'm trying to set up a category products list on my homepage following this [tutorial](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento/display-products-homepage).

```
<div class="hide-ratting owl-top-narrow" id="featured_product">
    {{block type="filterproducts/featured_home_list" name="new_list" product_count="10" category_id="3" aspect_ratio="1" lazy_owl="1" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
</div>
```

with below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(function(jQuery){
      jQuery("#featured_product .filter-products .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({items:4, lazyLoad: true,     nav: false,    autoPlay: true,    navText:["<i class='icon-left-open'></i>","<i class='icon-right-open'></i>"]});
    });
  // ]]></script>
```

The above slider works fine for my home page, but it only displays first 10 products for the mentioned category. I want to manage the products randomly as per sku. Whichever product's SKU I specify in the code that products only should be displayed in the slider, instead of first 10/20 products of category.

Is there any method to do that in Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new product attribute and then filter it out thought that attribute

Example - Attrubute name as home_page_slider (1 = enable /0 = disable [default])

then in collection

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('home_page_slider', 1);